# setPreferredInput WithBlueTooth not working

Tags: ios, bluetooth, audiosession

I'm trying to set bluetooth device  into preferinput in audioSession.

Here is my code:

```
if(speaker)
{
    NSLog(@"Audio use speaker");
    CGFloat set = 5.0f;
    AudioQueueSetParameter(audioQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, set);
    [sessionInstance overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker error:&error];

}else{
    NSLog(@"QCAudio use headset");
    NSError *audioError = nil;
    BOOL hasAvaliableBuleTooth = NO;
    NSArray* b_routePort = @[AVAudioSessionPortBluetoothHFP];
    NSArray* portDescArr = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
    AVAudioSessionPortDescription* desPortDesc;
    for (AVAudioSessionPortDescription* portDesc in portDescArr){
        if ([b_routePort containsObject:portDesc.portType])
        {
            desPortDesc = portDesc;
            hasAvaliableBuleTooth = YES;
        }
    }
    if (hasAvaliableBuleTooth == YES) {
        NSLog(@"1111111111 avsession  desportDesc = %@",desPortDesc);
        BOOL ret =[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setPreferredInput:desPortDesc error:&audioError];
        NSLog(@"ret = %d current route = %@",ret, [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] currentRoute]);
    }else{
        NSLog(@"222222222222 avsession");
        CGFloat set = 1.0f;
        AudioQueueSetParameter(audioQueue, kAudioQueueParam_Volume, set);
        [sessionInstance overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone
                                           error:&error];
    }
}
```

and I've got this sign:

> 2019-01-11 17:59:51.400283+0800 yichaoyun[4196:1228652] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port h.ear (MDR-EX750BT) (type: BluetoothHFP)
>
> 2019-01-11 17:59:51.400381+0800 yichaoyun[4196:1228652] 1111111111 avsession  desportDesc =
>
> 2019-01-11 17:59:51.410321+0800 yichaoyun[4196:1228652] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port h.ear (MDR-EX750BT) (type: BluetoothHFP)
>
> 2019-01-11 17:59:51.410357+0800 yichaoyun[4196:1228652] [avas] AVAudioSessionPortImpl.mm:56:ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port h.ear (MDR-EX750BT) (type: BluetoothHFP)
>
> 2019-01-11 17:59:51.410447+0800 yichaoyun[4196:1228652] ret = 1 current route = "
>   ); 
>   outputs = (
>       ""
>   )>

It shows that connect bluetooth device is success.but I can only hear some nosie.then it turned to silence.Is there only one who face the same question?How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you give me more details? like are you setting any Category of '[AVAudioSession sharedInstance]`? Or are you recording audio using bluetooth?

Comment: Hi,Mayur Karmur,thanks before!I seted it like:[sessionInstance setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&error];[ sessionInstance setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat error:&error ];

Comment: And I've got ret = 1 current route = <AVAudioSessionRouteDescription: 0x282789d00, inputs = ( "<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x282789da0, type = BluetoothHFP; name = h.ear (MDR-EX750BT); UID = 04:5D:4B:4A:4F:31-tsco; selectedDataSource = (null)>" ); outputs = ( "<AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x282789f60, type = BluetoothHFP; name = h.ear (MDR-EX750BT); UID = 04:5D:4B:4A:4F:31-tsco; selectedDataSource = (null)>" )>.    Can you help me  with this?

Comment: Okay. Check this class which may help you. https://github.com/Jawbone/AudioSessionManager

Comment: @Mubin Mall I've seen this before but it doesn't work for me ,thanks again

Comment: I finally find out the right answer!"setCategory"is preferred not to set many times! I seted it twice before.

Comment: That's great... Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the right answer.
`AVAudioSession` should be used to collect and record which is very important.

And then `setCategory` like this:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord 
withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&error];
```

Set preferinput:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setPreferredInput:_bluetoothPort error:nil];
```

When you got current input like this:

```
inputs = (
    "< AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x28185bf00, type = MicrophoneBuiltIn; name = iPhone \U9ea6\U514b\U98ce; UID = Built-In Microphone; selectedDataSource = \U524d >"
); 

outputs = (
    "< AVAudioSessionPortDescription: 0x28185bfb0, type = BluetoothA2DPOutput; name = h.ear (MDR-EX750BT); UID = 04:5D:4B:4A:4F:31-tacl; selectedDataSource = (null) >"
)>.
```

It works!  But I still don't understand why Apple's input shows that the prefer inputs is 'iPhone MicrophoneBuiltIn' but 'Bluetooth headphones' works.Is it a bug?